# How to read input from RTSP stream in C#?

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, rtsp, netcat

I have a server running serving RTSP streaming video content on **127.0.0.1:8554/nurv**

I am now trying to write a proxy that will read the stream from this location and pass it along via a socket connection to another application.

When I create a socket connection that listens on **127.0.0.1** and on port **8554** I don't receive any input. (I was expecting some incoming UDP packets, some of which contain the "nurv" path). I have tried the same in netcat and it keeps listening without receiving any input. Yet, when I visit **rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/nurv** from VLC then the content is displayed - so it is clearly there.

The current C# code I use to try and receive the stream is the following:

```
        IPEndPoint m_listenEp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8554);
        Socket m_UdpListenSocket = new Socket(m_listenEp.Address.AddressFamily, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

        m_UdpListenSocket.Bind(m_listenEp);

        while (true)
        {
            if (m_UdpListenSocket.Available > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Data available");
                ...
            }
        }
```

In netcat, when I run *nc 127.0.0.1 8554* it just keeps listening and seems to be waiting for a response. I don't see any output. I don't know if that has anything to do with the fact that the content is being served in the **/nurv** path?

This is probably a very newbie question highlighting a shortcoming in my understanding of networking, but why don't I see any input when listening on the specified location? And how could I go about reading the stream in C# so that I have it available to pass along a different socket connection to the other application?

Comment: Probably, server waits some data from you. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol

Comment: I think you're probably right...so basic...just didn't see the forest through the trees there. :-) I'll try and use netcat to look at the traffic between VLC and the server so that I can issue similar "play" commands first...then I should be able to start receiving the actual data.